Two input columns in HTML table row, but only first one works
I'm building a mapping application where users can add Features to a database and then, on the mapping page, have the features listed in an HTML table.  There are 3 columns in the table: Feature Name, Selected (this is an input control with an on/off slider switch) and Color (this is an input control of type="color" to display a color picker to differentiate the features).  When the "Display" button is clicked, all of the Lats/Longs for each selected Feature are retrieved from the database and a Pin for all locations of each Feature is placed on the map with the selected color for that Feature.
My problem is this:  Only the first input control in each row is working: e.g. If I have the switch control first, it works fine but the color picker doesn't work and vice versa.
Here is the relevant code (this sample has the switch first):
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeatureName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Selected
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Color
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FeatureName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="color" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

I'm not a Bootstrap guru, so any help with how to declare the input controls would be VERY much appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!
Bob

Figured it out - was using the wrong Bootstrap 5 classes.  The first control (switch) should be:
<input class="form-control form-check-input" type="checkbox"/>

and the second control (color-picker) should be:
<input class="form-control form-control-color" type="color"/>

Hope this can be useful to somebody!
